# Dynamically Generate Complex Action Combinations

Tags: java, math, formula

I have a web page with input fields and clickable buttons. I would like to know the formula to dynamically generate all possible field combinations?

For example, assuming there are two actions that can be performed on any given page - either a click (button) action or a send input action and the page contains 4 input fields and 3 buttons.

Suppose I need to perform two send input actions - send username and send password and click 1 button (1 click action) - what is the formula to generate all possible combinations if the number of fields/actions can change?

This is just an example - the number of actions might change from 2 (click and send input) to 3 or more (such as click, send input and select checkbox). Similarly, the number of actions being performed might change - we might need to send 3 input and perform two clicks. Finally, the number of possible actions on page can also change - instead of there being 4 input fields on the page there might be 8 input fields or more than 2 buttons.

To illustrate with a simple example if I can choose from two actions (click and send text actions) with a page that contains 3 input fields and 1 button and I need to perform 2 send input actions (password and username) and 1 click action (click login) here are the possible combinations expected:

1. Send username to input field 1 and password to input field 2 + click btn 1
2. Send username to input field 1 and password to input field 3 + click btn 1
3. Send username to input field 2 and password to input field 3 + click btn 1
4. Send username to input field 3 and password to input field 2 + click btn 1
5. Send username to input field 2 and password to input field 1 + click btn 1
6. Send username to input field 3 and password to input field 1 + click btn 1

Note: There are no overlapping actions - in other words we cannot send input to the same field at the same time.

This is a simple example I would like to be able to generate all possible combinations with the dynamic needs described above.. namely:

1. The number of possible actions types might change from two (click, send input) to 3 or more.
2. The number of actual actions being performed on each type (or the "action target") can change from 2 (send username, send password) to any number
3. The page may contain any number of input fields, button and select-able boxes etc

I'm using Java so I prefer a Java example if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. please provide some code of what you have tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) might help to understand the formula.  Post some code if you get stuck.